# Exponential distribution with an upper bound

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

An exponential distribution is often used to model the lifespan of a component with a constant failure rate. What is a suitable distribution to use in the situation where a component has a constant failure rate $\lambda$ but that after a certain time $T$ if the part has not failed it is replaced anyway?

The question is whether there is a continuous distribution that approximates the following:
$$f(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0,\\
\lambda  e^{-(\lambda x)} & x \ge 0 <T \\
1 & x\ge T.
\end{cases}$$

My best guess would be to use an appropriately scaled $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution.

I haven't worked it out fully but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would obviously need to depend on $\lambda$ and $T$. For instance when $T >> \lambda$ the exponential distribution again would be a fair approximation. [image]

Edited: added explicit definition of the distribution following 5201314's contribution.

Comment: The $f(x;\lambda)$ that you write is not a density function at all. The lifetime is not a _continuous_ random variable but a _mixed_ random variable that has an  _atom_ at $T$ and a continuous density on $[0,T)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a time to failure $X$, constant failure rate $\lambda$ and given that it is replaced after a certain time $T$ if it hasn't failed, $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
1-e^{-\lambda x}, & x<T\\
1, & x\ge T
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Arguably though, it is just a restatement of the problem in terms of the cdf. I concede I should have been more explicit when defining the distribution that I'm trying to approximate: $$f(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0,\\
\lambda  e^{-(\lambda x)} & x \ge 0 <T \\
1 & x\ge T.
\end{cases}$$
I'll amend the original post to reflect your influence.